# React get metamask latest transaction status

Tags: reactjs, web3js, metamask

I am using this, to make a function call in smart contract via metamask in react:

```
export default class EthereumForm1 extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
    const MyContract = window.web3.eth.contract(ContractABI);

    this.state = {
      ContractInstance: MyContract.at('ContractAddress')
    }
    this.doPause = this.doPause.bind (this);
}
  doPause() {
    const { pause } = this.state.ContractInstance;

    pause (
      {
        gas: 30000,
        gasPrice: 32000000000,
        value: window.web3.toWei (0, 'ether')
      },
      (err) => {
      if (err) console.error ('Error1::::', err);
      console.log ('Contract should be paused');
    })
  }
```

What I want is to run jQuery code with loading gif: `$(".Loading").show();`
while transaction is being processed and remove it after. Also, it would be good to add transaction status in div after, like in metamask(either passed or rejected).

[image: Metamask transaction status image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped me was checking every few seconds if my transactiopn finished, and if yes hiding the loader.

```
if (latestTx != null) {
  window.web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(latestTx, function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
      $(".Loading").hide();
      console.error ('Error1::::', error);
    }
    console.log(result);
    if(result != null){
      latestTx = null;
      $(".Loading").hide();
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery to do this. React state can manage the status of the progress automatically. All you have to do is to call `setState` function.

```
class EthereumFrom1 extends React.Component {

    state = {
        loading: false
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.doPause = this.doPause.bind(this);

    }

    doPause() {
        const {pause} = this.state.ContractInstance;

        pause(
            {
                gas: 30000,
                gasPrice: 32000000000,
                value: window.web3.toWei(0, 'ether')
            },
            (err) => {
                if (err) console.error('Error1::::', err);
                this.setState({loading: true});
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.loading ?
                    <div className="Loading">
                        Loading...
                    </div> : <div>done</div>
                }
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this works only halfway through. Because when transaction is mined, state does not change back(it does not matter if it was Success, fail or reverted also, still gives same result).